# npm ping is opening command prompt windows

Tags: node.js, npm, ping, pm2

I want to ping certain IPs in a project, and I am using npm ping package for this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping

When I run the service, its running fine. But when is run my service in the PM2, the command prompt windows are showing up, each time the ping action is done in that service(I am pinging in loops to monitor an IP).

What is the reason for this and please suggest an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me while using `forever` to run my script in background.

I've found that using `START /B node script.js` on windows instead of `forever` worked just fine and the command prompt didn't showed up. I don't know much about PM2 but maybe you should be able to prefix your command with `START /B` somewhere in PM2 or just run your script by yourself.